# Can you view the Perseid meteor shower anywhere on Earth?

Tags: meteor-shower

The peak viewing dates of the 2016 [Perseid Meteor Shower](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseids) is said to be between the dates of August 11 through the early morning hours of August 12.

Being a resident of the United States, I keep getting my peak viewing dates and times for my area and for the whole of the [United States](http://www.space.com/33713-perseid-meteor-shower-us-weather-forecast-2016.html).  There is never any mention of any other parts of the world having the capability to view this meteor shower.

**Is the Perseid Meteor Shower visible to all parts of the world?**

Comment: [This question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseids) is similar. With the radiant at around +58 degrees declination, observers south of **approximately** 32 degrees South will see very few, if any, meteors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see perseid meteors from all the Northern Hemisphere, and the Northern part of the Southern Hemisphere. Provided the sky is clear, the moon has set, and Perseus is above the horizon you will see meteors. This shower has a wide peak, so you can see them over several nights.